# Need help collecting data from buttons pressed. [Python]

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to create a roulette table (which I have done as a GUI). Now, when I press the button for the outcome it shows the number in my top box, but I'm struggling to find a way to collect the results in a list, so I can then later pull data from the list.

For example, I want a list of past results so that I could show that's it's been 4 spins without landing on a odd number or it's been 3 spins since it's been red, or on average it lands in the 1st 12 every 3 spins.

I have tried numerous ways of collecting results from the buttons clicked but nothing works.

```
from tkinter import*


# Roulette GUI


root = Tk()
root.title("Roulette")


e = Entry(root, width=200, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=13, padx=10, pady=10)


def button_click(number):
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)
    print(number)

   

# define buttons


button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=84, bg='green', command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_10 = Button(root, text="10", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(10))
button_11 = Button(root, text="11", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(11))
button_12 = Button(root, text="12", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(12))
button_13 = Button(root, text="13", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(13))
button_14 = Button(root, text="14", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(14))
button_15 = Button(root, text="15", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(15))
button_16 = Button(root, text="16", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(16))
button_17 = Button(root, text="17", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(17))
button_18 = Button(root, text="18", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(18))
button_19 = Button(root, text="19", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(19))
button_20 = Button(root, text="20", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(20))
button_21 = Button(root, text="21", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(21))
button_22 = Button(root, text="22", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(22))
button_23 = Button(root, text="23", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(23))
button_24 = Button(root, text="24", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(24))
button_25 = Button(root, text="25", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(25))
button_26 = Button(root, text="26", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(26))
button_27 = Button(root, text="27", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(27))
button_28 = Button(root, text="28", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(28))
button_29 = Button(root, text="29", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(29))
button_30 = Button(root, text="30", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(30))
button_31 = Button(root, text="31", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(31))
button_32 = Button(root, text="32", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(32))
button_33 = Button(root, text="33", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(33))
button_34 = Button(root, text="34", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(34))
button_35 = Button(root, text="35", padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda: button_click(35))
button_36 = Button(root, text="36", padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda: button_click(36))
button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", padx=60, pady=20, command=root.quit)

# put buttons on the screen

button_0.grid(row=1, rowspan=3, column=0)
button_1.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_4.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_6.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_7.grid(row=3, column=3)
button_8.grid(row=2, column=3)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=3)
button_10.grid(row=3, column=4)
button_11.grid(row=2, column=4)
button_12.grid(row=1, column=4)
button_13.grid(row=3, column=5)
button_14.grid(row=2, column=5)
button_15.grid(row=1, column=5)
button_16.grid(row=3, column=6)
button_17.grid(row=2, column=6)
button_18.grid(row=1, column=6)
button_19.grid(row=3, column=7)
button_20.grid(row=2, column=7)
button_21.grid(row=1, column=7)
button_22.grid(row=3, column=8)
button_23.grid(row=2, column=8)
button_24.grid(row=1, column=8)
button_25.grid(row=3, column=9)
button_26.grid(row=2, column=9)
button_27.grid(row=1, column=9)
button_28.grid(row=3, column=10)
button_29.grid(row=2, column=10)
button_30.grid(row=1, column=10)
button_31.grid(row=3, column=11)
button_32.grid(row=2, column=11)
button_33.grid(row=1, column=11)
button_34.grid(row=3, column=12)
button_35.grid(row=2, column=12)
button_36.grid(row=1, column=12)
button_exit.grid(row=4, column=11, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No idea what your question is

Comment: Hi CT86, in addition to saying that you've tried multiple things, it would be useful to know what you have tried. Can you add a few more lines describing the code you've tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can't you use `my_list.append( number )` in function `button_click()` ?

Comment: @roganjosh "but I'm struggling to find a way TO COLLECT THE RESULTS IN A LIST , so I can then later pull data from the list"

Comment: @furas when i press any of the buttons i want it to add that number to my list, so if i pressed red 1 i want it to add 1 to my list.... i have tried my_list.append(number) but i cannot get it to work, im a total newbie to coding

Comment: did you add `my_list.append( number )` in function `button_click`? Did you create empty `my_list = []` at start ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to see percentage of pressing red and black buttons, this code print it on your console

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.title("Roulette")
e = Entry(root, width=200, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=13, padx=10, pady=10)
results = []
def button_click(number):
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)
    results.append(number)
    #loop through results
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if results[i]%2 == 0:
            count += 1
    print("Number is",number)
    red_percentage = count/len(results)*100
    print("Black", 100-red_percentage)
    print("Red", red_percentage)
    print("------------------------------------")
    
# define buttons
button = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=84, bg='green', command=lambda: button_click(0))
button.grid(row=1, rowspan=3, column=0)
for i in range(0,36):
    if i%2 == 0:
        button = Button(root, text=str(i+1), padx=40, pady=20, bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda i=i:button_click(i+1))
    else:
        button = Button(root, text=str(i+1), padx=40, pady=20, bg='red', command=lambda i=i: button_click(i+1))
    button.grid(row=3 - i%3, column=int(i/3) + 1)

button = Button(root, text="Exit", padx=60, pady=20, command=root.quit)
button.grid(row=4, column=11, columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Shoaib i was more after sequences, so how many times it has or hasnt been a particular colour or area

Comment: Only thing lacking here is a bit of explanation. Maybe also keep track of the count the button is pressed each round.